# How do I communicate with my stateless component in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I wanted to create a very simple app containing a button. When I click on it it should change it's name and should change it's state to: `isDisabled:true`. I accomplished this by writing  button inline, giving it an OnClick and so on, but I wanted to try this with stateless component with the same functionality, however I'm totally stuck.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component{
 constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {name:'Hey buddy click me',
   isDisabled:false,
  }
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <MyButton handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}></MyButton>
       </div>
    )
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState ({
      name:'Dont click!',
      isDisabled:true,
  });

  }
}

const MyButton = (name, isDisabled) => <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{name}</button>

export default App;
```

Comment: Can we have a working, minimal example?

Comment: you are calling handle click in `Button` component, but that's not been passed to your button component. So handleClick will not be accessible there in button component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `name, isDisabled` too with `handleClick` as props if you want to access then in `MyButton` component.

Though name can also be passed as children. But as i feel you are learning start passing it as props.Then in future you can use children.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component{
 constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {name:'Hey buddy click me',
   isDisabled:false,
  }
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <MyButton
         name={this.state.name}
         isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled}
         handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
       </MyButton>
      </div>
    )
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState ({
      name:'Dont click!',
      isDisabled:true,
  });

  }
}
//here we need to receive props from parent components, if we need to use here
const MyButton = ({name, isDisabled, handleClick}) => <button onClick={handleClick}>{name}</button>

export default App;
```

Comment: So I need to pass a  handleClick method to MyButton because handleClick is a part of App class, yes?

Comment: You were already passing that to `handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}` MyButton. But was not receiving that properly in `MyButton`. If you will see the solution i have written above just received that properly along with other expected props.